# Is it feasible to use Elasticsearch with .Net Core 2.2 & how to configure it to fetch a simple get query API?

Tags: asp.net, api, elasticsearch, .net-core

I need to migrate from SQL Server to Elasticsearch. Hence wanted to know whether it is feasible to use Elasticsearch with .Net Core 2.2. If yes, an example for configuring a simple fetch query API would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** 
Yes.

**How:**

Elasticsearch operates on [REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html) and every language in the world has a way to call http endpoints.

For more seamless integration with dot net, Elasticsearch has a [.net api client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html) as well. I would recommend you to use REST api however as it helps in easy testing and easily managing the query files in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

I am little late to the game, but I have done application that serves as migration tool from SQL Server to Elasticsearch. It can only handle 1 table at the moment, but you can check: https://github.com/Ryukote/ElasticDatabaseHook